# Use gpg password from pass as variable in a script

Tags: gnupg, mutt

I try to create an autologin to use posteo within neomutt.

Is it possible to use the gpg file from the pass folder

> .password-store/

in a .muttrc config?

In the Mutt Archwiki there is the following Password-Manger section:

1.create file and input

```
set my_pass = "password"
```

2.encrypt the file and call the gpg in muttrc

```
source "gpg -dq $HOME/.my-pwds.gpg |"
```

3.call password in a script

```
set imap_pass=$my_pass
```

This should work, but i want to use my existing pass gpg file directly. I have the passport gpg file decrypted for testing, but the file only contains the password without an addition. How to use this password as a variable in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem

1.Copy gpg.rc from samples

```
cp /usr/share/doc/neomutt/samples/gpg.rc ~/.mutt
```

My .neomuttrc use a source file like this:

```
source ~/.mutt/gpg.rc                               

set my_pass=`pass Email/...`   

# Receive options                                 
set from="user@posteo.de"                     
set hostname="posteo.de"                                     
set realname='urename'                           
set imap_login='user@posteo.de'               
set imap_pass=$my_pass                                 
set folder="imaps://user@posteo.de@posteo.de/"
set spoolfile="=INBOX"                                 
set record="=Sent"                            
set postponed="=Drafts"                       

# Send options                                                                      
smtp_url="                                                                
set from="user@posteo.de"                                            

# Hook                                                                        
account-hook $folder "set imap_user=user@posteo.de imap_pass=$my_pass"
```